# Array of Object in Colletion Fistore Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have Array of Object in collection in firestore. When I call the collection(Orders) to get single order, it retrieve all feild correctly expect of Array of Object which named "foods".

Get reference to the order

```
    mOrderRef = mFirestore.collection("orders").document(orderId);
```

onEvent function

```
   @Override
   public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, 
   FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
     if (e != null) {
         Log.w(TAG, "order:onEvent", e);
         return;
     }


     onOrderLoaded(documentSnapshot.toObject(Order.class));
  }
```

onOrderLoaded function

```
    private void onOrderLoaded(Order order) {


    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(order.getMenu())); // why is printing null?

   }
```

this is a full code of order class

```
      @IgnoreExtraProperties
   public class Order {

public static final String FIELD_USER_NAME = "username";
public static final String FIELD_USER_PHONE = "user_phone_number";
public static final String FIELD_USER_ID = "user_id";
public static final String FIELD_RESTAURANT_NAME = "restaurant_name";
public static final String FIELD_RESTAURANT_ID = "restaurant_id";
public static final String FIELD_STATUS = "status";
public static final String FIELD_SUBMITTED_AT = "submitted_at";
public static final String FIELD_TOTAL_COST = "total_cost";
public static final String FIELD_MENU = "foods";

private String username;
private String user_phone_number;
private String user_id;
private String restaurant_id;
private String restaurant_name;
private String status;
private Date submitted_at;
private Integer total_cost;
private Menu[] foods;

public Order() {}

public Order(String user_name, String user_phone_number, String user_id, String restaurant_id, String restaurant_name, String status, Date submitted_at, Integer total_cost, Menu[] foods) {
    this.username = user_name;
    this.user_phone_number = user_phone_number;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.restaurant_id = restaurant_id;
    this.restaurant_name = restaurant_name;
    this.status = status;
    this.submitted_at = submitted_at;
    this.total_cost = total_cost;
    this.foods = foods;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUser_phone_number() {
    return user_phone_number;
}

public void setUser_phone_number(String user_phone_number) {
    this.user_phone_number = user_phone_number;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getRestaurant_id() {
    return restaurant_id;
}

public void setRestaurant_id(String restaurant_id) {
    this.restaurant_id = restaurant_id;
}

public String getRestaurant_name() {
    return restaurant_name;
}

public void setRestaurant_name(String restaurant_name) {
    this.restaurant_name = restaurant_name;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getSubmitted_at() {
    return submitted_at;
}

public void setSubmitted_at(Date submitted_at) {
    this.submitted_at = submitted_at;
}

public Integer getTotal_cost() {
    return total_cost;
}

public void setTotal_cost(Integer total_cost) {
    this.total_cost = total_cost;
}

public Menu[] getMenu() {
    return foods;
}

public void setMenu(Menu[] foods) {
    this.foods = foods;
}
   }
```

Menu model

```
public class Menu {

    public static final String FIELD_ID = "id";
    public static final String FIELD_NAME = "name";
    public static final String FIELD_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    public static final String FIELD_PRICE = "price";

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String quantity;
    private String price;


    public Menu() {}

    public Menu(String id, String name, String quantity, String price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // Getter and Setter

}
```

I have Order collection on firestore with field Array of object, the question is how to Map the list of Menu model?

Firestore:
[image]

Comment: Hi Zana, it looks like you forgot to add the question itself. What are you looking for? Is it the comment where you mention it prints null?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: kindly complete public class Order, and where's you database schema ?

Comment: Yes the the question is the why value is null, and how to map the value of Menu model? Order class updated.

Comment: Any answer?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without your database rules or document creation code it is hard to tell but it appears your Menu model is being stored as a subcollection of the Order model. [FireStore only performs "shallow" queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb#major_differences_to_consider) so you need to perform an additional query to get all the documents of your Menu subcollection for a particular Order document.

Comment: I updated my question, you can see the screenshot of Firestore. its not subcollection, its stored as Array of Object. "foods" field.